# Replace characters during Infile with SCAN and TRANWRD

Tags: sas

Nearly there with this now, just got one final fix I have noticed on some of the files I am reading in. The code I am posting is part of a macro which loops over similar files. The older raw files have forward slashes instead of dashes, which I am trying to replace at read in stage with no luck. SAS is returning missing values for these:

```
data test;
        infile "&filename" 
        delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
        length
        EventTypes 8
        EventLabels $21
        EventID 8
        Player_ID 8
        ExpandedMinute 8
        Second 8
        TeamID 8
        EndY 8
        EndX 8
        Y 8
        X 8
        IsTouch $5
        ID 8
        Minute 8
        Period $10
        Type $25
        OutcomeType $12
        Area1 $25
        Area2 $25
        ParamVal1 $15
        ParamVal2 $15
        MatchID 8
        MatchDate 8
        HomeTeamName $100
        AwayTeamName $100
        FTScore $5
        HomeScore 8
        AwayScore 8 
        ;
        informat EventTypes best32. ;
        informat EventLabels $21. ;
        informat EventID best32. ;
        informat Player_ID best32. ;
        informat ExpandedMinute best32. ;
        informat Second best32. ;
        informat TeamID best32. ;
        informat EndY best32. ;
        informat EndX best32. ;
        informat Y best32. ;
        informat X best32. ;
        informat IsTouch $5. ;
        informat ID best32. ;
        informat Minute best32. ;
        informat Period $10. ;
        informat Type $25. ;
        informat OutcomeType $12. ;
        informat Area1 $25. ;
        informat Area2 $25. ;
        informat ParamVal1 $15. ;
        informat ParamVal2 $15. ;
        informat MatchID best32. ;
        informat MatchDate ddmmyy10. ;
        informat HomeTeamName $100. ;
        informat AwayTeamName $100. ;
        informat FTScore $5. ;
        informat HomeScore best32. ;
        informat AwayScore best32. ;
        format EventTypes best12. ;
        format EventLabels $21. ;
        format EventID best12. ;
        format Player_ID best12. ;
        format ExpandedMinute best12. ;
        format Second best12. ;
        format TeamID best12. ;
        format EndY best12. ;
        format EndX best12. ;
        format Y best12. ;
        format X best12. ;
        format IsTouch $5. ;
        format ID best12. ;
        format Minute best12. ;
        format Period $10. ;
        format Type $25. ;
        format OutcomeType $12. ;
        format Area1 $25. ;
        format Area2 $25. ;
        format ParamVal1 $15. ;
        format ParamVal2 $15. ;
        format MatchID best12. ;
        format MatchDate ddmmyy10. ;
        format HomeTeamName $100. ;
        format AwayTeamName $100. ;
        format FTScore $5. ;
        format HomeScore best12. ;
        format AwayScore best12. ;
        input
        EventTypes
        EventLabels $
        EventID
        Player_ID
        ExpandedMinute
        Second
        TeamID
        EndY
        EndX
        Y
        X
        IsTouch $
        ID
        Minute
        Period $
        Type $
        OutcomeType $
        Area1 $
        Area2 $ @;
        if scan(_infile_,20,',') not in ('Back', 'Defence', 'Forward', 'Left', 'Midfield', 'Right') then 
        input ParamVal1 @;
        else 
        input ParamVal2 @;
        input
        MatchID @;
        MatchDate = tranwrd((scan(_infile_,21,',')), "/", "-");
        input MatchDate @;
        input
        HomeTeamName $
        AwayTeamName $
        FTScore $
        HomeScore
        AwayScore;
        if ParamVal1 = '' then ParamVal1 = '0';
        if ParamVal2 = '' then ParamVal2 = 'None';
        run;
```

Can anyone suggest an amendment to the above to get this to work?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As requested, here is a raw data line that is generating an missing value:

```
118,shortPassAccurate,3,4511,0,5,24,48.5,51.1,52.2,49.4,True,1394118243.0,0,FirstHalf,Start,Successful,PassEndX,None,51.1,410988,08/14/2010,Aston Villa,West Ham,3 : 0,3,0,
```

The job log looks like this:

```
Record: _410988_08_14_2010 processed successfully. Processing next record...
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0
2         0,None,2,0,0,0,24,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,False,1505579494.0,0,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,0.0,410988
     101  ,08/14/2010,Aston Villa,West Ham,3 : 0,3,0, 143
EventTypes=0 EventLabels=None EventID=2 Player_ID=0 ExpandedMinute=0 Second=0 TeamID=24 EndY=0 EndX=0 Y=0 X=0 IsTouch=False
ID=1505579494 Minute=0 Period=NoQual Type=NoQual OutcomeType=NoQual Area1=NoQual Area2=NoQual ParamVal1=0.0 ParamVal2=None
MatchID=410988 MatchDate=. HomeTeamName=Aston Villa AwayTeamName=West Ham FTScore=3 : 0 HomeScore=3 AwayScore=0 _ERROR_=1
_INFILE_=0,None,2,0,0,0,24,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,False,1505579494.0,0,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,0.0,410988,08/14/2010,Aston Villa,
West Ham,3 : 0,3,0, _N_=1
3         0,None,2,0,0,0,29,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,False,49800133.0,0,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,0.0,410988,0
     101  8/14/2010,Aston Villa,West Ham,3 : 0,3,0, 141
EventTypes=0 EventLabels=None EventID=2 Player_ID=0 ExpandedMinute=0 Second=0 TeamID=29 EndY=0 EndX=0 Y=0 X=0 IsTouch=False
ID=49800133 Minute=0 Period=NoQual Type=NoQual OutcomeType=NoQual Area1=NoQual Area2=NoQual ParamVal1=0.0 ParamVal2=None
MatchID=410988 MatchDate=. HomeTeamName=Aston Villa AwayTeamName=West Ham FTScore=3 : 0 HomeScore=3 AwayScore=0 _ERROR_=1
_INFILE_=0,None,2,0,0,0,29,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,False,49800133.0,0,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,NoQual,0.0,410988,08/14/2010,Aston Villa,We
st Ham,3 : 0,3,0, _N_=2
4         90,midThird,3,4511,0,5,24,48.5,51.1,52.2,49.4,True,1394118243.0,0,FirstHalf,Start,Successful,PassEnd
     101  Y,None,48.5,410988,08/14/2010,Aston Villa,West Ham,3 : 0,3,0, 161
EventTypes=90 EventLabels=midThird EventID=3 Player_ID=4511 ExpandedMinute=0 Second=5 TeamID=24 EndY=48.5 EndX=51.1 Y=52.2 X=49.4
IsTouch=True ID=1394118243 Minute=0 Period=FirstHalf Type=Start OutcomeType=Successful Area1=PassEndY Area2=None ParamVal1=48.5
ParamVal2=None MatchID=410988 MatchDate=. HomeTeamName=Aston Villa AwayTeamName=West Ham FTScore=3 : 0 HomeScore=3 AwayScore=0
_ERROR_=1
_INFILE_=90,midThird,3,4511,0,5,24,48.5,51.1,52.2,49.4,True,1394118243.0,0,FirstHalf,Start,Successful,PassEndY,None,48.5,410988,08/14
/2010,Aston Villa,West Ham,3 : 0,3,0, _N_=3
5         90,midThird,3,4511,0,5,24,48.5,51.1,52.2,49.4,True,1394118243.0,0,FirstHalf,Start,Successful,Length,
     101  None,3.1,410988,08/14/2010,Aston Villa,West Ham,3 : 0,3,0, 158
EventTypes=90 EventLabels=midThird EventID=3 Player_ID=4511 ExpandedMinute=0 Second=5 TeamID=24 EndY=48.5 EndX=51.1 Y=52.2 X=49.4
IsTouch=True ID=1394118243 Minute=0 Period=FirstHalf Type=Start OutcomeType=Successful Area1=Length Area2=None ParamVal1=3.1
ParamVal2=None MatchID=410988 MatchDate=. HomeTeamName=Aston Villa AwayTeamName=West Ham FTScore=3 : 0 HomeScore=3 AwayScore=0
_ERROR_=1
_INFILE_=90,midThird,3,4511,0,5,24,48.5,51.1,52.2,49.4,True,1394118243.0,0,FirstHalf,Start,Successful,Length,None,3.1,410988,08/14/20
10,Aston Villa,West Ham,3 : 0,3,0, _N_=4
6         90,midThird,3,4511,0,5,24,48.5,51.1,52.2,49.4,True,1394118243.0,0,FirstHalf,Start,Successful,Angle,N
     101  one,5.3,410988,08/14/2010,Aston Villa,West Ham,3 : 0,3,0, 157
EventTypes=90 EventLabels=midThird EventID=3 Player_ID=4511 ExpandedMinute=0 Second=5 TeamID=24 EndY=48.5 EndX=51.1 Y=52.2 X=49.4
IsTouch=True ID=1394118243 Minute=0 Period=FirstHalf Type=Start OutcomeType=Successful Area1=Angle Area2=None ParamVal1=5.3
ParamVal2=None MatchID=410988 MatchDate=. HomeTeamName=Aston Villa AwayTeamName=West Ham FTScore=3 : 0 HomeScore=3 AwayScore=0
_ERROR_=1
_INFILE_=90,midThird,3,4511,0,5,24,48.5,51.1,52.2,49.4,True,1394118243.0,0,FirstHalf,Start,Successful,Angle,None,5.3,410988,08/14/201
0,Aston Villa,West Ham,3 : 0,3,0, _N_=5
```

Comment: Post examples of the values that are causing the problem.  SAS should happily read both `30/12/2015` and `30-12-2015` using the `DDMMYY10.` informat.

Comment: I, thanks for replying. I have amended to show a raw line of data and the job log.

Comment: There is no 8th day of the 14th month in the calendar.  Try using ANYDTDTE. informat instead as it would automatically convert that to August 14th instead.  But if the rest of the data lines work with DDMMYY informat then I think you have a bigger issue.

Answer (score 1):

The value is missing because there is no month 14.  Is it posisble that the value is in MMDDYY format instead of DDMMYY format? What about for the other lines of your source file?

Perhaps you should read the field as a character string and then analyze to see if the values are consistent with one date format.  If the value is not entered in a consistent format then you will need to have some additional information to help figure out whether ambiguous values like 05/05/2015 are in MDY are DMY format.

Personally I tell data suppliers to output their dates in YMD format to avoid this confusion.

Comment: i hadnt actually noticed the issue with the date, so thanks for pointing that out. im using SAS 9.0 which doesnt appear to have ANYDTDTE loaded, so I am going to have to load in as a character string and think about changing he date format once I have a completed dataset.